# Java web service/AngularJS - sometimes API's body received partially with gibberish

Tags: angularjs, web-services, nginx

I'm trying to understand why sometimes (only sometimes and not all the time) the same API call body arrives to the server in corrupted format (partially with gibberish) in spite of the fact that from the browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) it is sent properly.
I Will be glad to hear any ideas!

***API call example (same as sent from browser)***:

- Request URL: https://localhost/api/web/getMainData
- Request Method: POST
- Remote Address: 123.45.67.89:443
- Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

***Response Headers***:

- cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
- content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
- date: Wed, 16 Mar 2022 11:16:43 GMT
- expires: 0
- pragma: no-cache
- server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)            ---> *used proxy server*

***Request headers***:

- :authority: quilliup-trn.advantagegroup.com
- :method: POST
- :path: /api/web/getMainData
- :scheme: https
- accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
- accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
- accept-language: en,en-US;q=0.9
- content-length: 10157
- content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
- cookie: JSESSIONID=3C1DB6D3A840B2703F27431966F92B5E
- guid: 5c24e7ab-75b6-4339-af02-51e310b21727
- origin: https://localhost
- referer: https://localhost/
- sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"
- sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
- sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
- sec-fetch-dest: empty
- sec-fetch-mode: cors
- sec-fetch-site: same-origin
- user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36

***Payload/Body***:

```
{
  "id": "abc44b66-847d-4805-ae7d-f0285cf3d123",
  "filterOptions": {
    "advancedTxt": "",
    "operand": "or",
    "advanced": {}
  },
  "filterDDOptions": {
    "advanced": {}
  },
  "pageSize": 100,
  "pageNumber": 1,
  "responseStructure": [...],
  "sortinfo": {
    "fields": [
      "Company Code"
    ],
    "directions": [
      "asc"
    ]
  }
}
```

***Error from log file***:

"... received json body is:
� 5ۂ� �`u��N; $RXz��*C ��F �|�� ѕf��Vy׀���/6��p$� 2N]� �l�.4�B&@�=�]��R'$��H(�mgٔ�4�2,�%�i �i� � �׾����������tions":{"advanced":{}},"pageSize":100,"pageNumber":1,"responseStructure":[{"displayName":"Company Code" ..."

***Additional details***:

- Java 1.8.0_302
- AngularJS
- nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu) - used proxy server

Comment: You are telling the server your payload will be in UTF-8. Are you making sure it actually is in UTF-8?

Comment: Hi.  Do you mean making sure it actually is in UTF-8 when sent from proxy? In any case, I guess that if the problem was related to encoding, it would not work all the time. In in our case it succeeds in most of cases and fails only sometimes.

Comment: hmm yes you are right, i overread that part.